# spring social facebook specific graph api version requests

Tags: facebook-graph-api, spring-social, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, spring-social-facebook

Is it possible to change graph api level for spring social facebook api. 
After getting access token, making a request with restOperationsApi and putting graph api version parameter to url does not work.

```
facebook.restOperations().getForObject("https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/{pageId}/notes
```

This request result is "{"error":{"message":"(#12) notes API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher","type":"OAuthException","code":12}}"

When I debug response from facebook, i see in request header facebook app version is v2.1 even i put parameter to request url.

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#12) notes API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher", **Facebook-API-Version: v2.1**,

Thanks.

Comment: If your app was created after API v2.0 was introduced, then you will not be able to “downgrade” it to using v1.0 any more.

Comment: My app is able to user v1.0 api, when i try with facebook Graph API Explorer with Api Level 1.0 response is correct. But spring social facebook api, sending requests without version so facebook response with latest graph api version 2.1 - I need to change api level version or i need to execute facebook.restOperations().getForObject("https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/{pageId}/notes this code.

Comment: Well then you will have to figure out how/where spring social set the API version to be used. (But be aware that your app will stop working in this regard next year when v1.0 is retired anyway … so consider whether it is actually still worth putting any effort in this functionality now …?)